# unresolved external symbol using curl NuGet

Tags: curl, nuget, visual-studio-2017, libcurl

environment:

> microsoft visual studio 2017
>   NuGet package manager
>   C++ project

workflow:

> 1. I added curl using NuGet
> 2. I attempted to compile my project
> 3. it throws 8 linker errors "unresolved external symbol"

project structure:

```
 root  
   -> packages  

   ----> curl.7.30.0.2  
   -------->  build     
   -------->  tools  

   ----> curl.redist.7.30.0.2  
   -------->  build

   ----> libssh2.1.4.3.1
```

(this is not the entire directory structure, the point is there seems to be a lot of choice with regards to which curl dll I could add to the environment.)

Any ideas on how to get this working?